# "Soft Questions" in StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I just noticed in math.stackexchange (and maybe other sites on the network) there's a tag named "soft-question":

> For questions whose answers can't be objectively evaluated as correct or incorrect, but which are still relevant to this site.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question

Is there a place for this type of questions here, too? Was this considered in the past?

Here's an example of a soft question from Math:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154/do-complex-numbers-really-exist?rq=1

Comment: As I understand it soft questions are just questions without a definitive answer, something like "how to produce really random numbers with a computer". They are so diverse and rare that a dedicated tag for them is probably hard to deduce. Just tag them according to their other content.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was considered; [we even spun up an entire site specifically dedicated to those types of questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes/200144#200144). It [started out](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3412/what-is-the-history-behind-the-site-scope-change-from-npr-to-conceptual-questio) known as "Not Programming Related", changed to "Programmers", and is now called ["Software Engineering"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com). The scope of that site changed, too, over time, because "soft questions" aren't good fodder for our type of Q&A.

Additionally, [soft-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) is a "meta" tag, like [homework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework), which means that it does not describe the content of the question, and therefore [should not exist on any Stack Exchange site](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). A tag like that definitely won't exist here on Stack Overflow. It serves no purpose.

However…[the cited question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154/do-complex-numbers-really-exist) is not a problem, and its equivalent could be asked here on Stack Overflow today.